# Apache Camel: Accessing CamelLoopIndex

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following route DSL:

```
from("file:" + autoLoadBaseDir + "?move=.classified")
                .loop(fileTypes.length)
                    .choice()
                        .when(header("CamelFileName").contains(fileTypes[Integer.valueOf("${CamelLoopIndex}")]))
                            .to("file:" + classesBaseDir + "/" + fileTypes[Integer.valueOf("${CamelLoopIndex}")]);
```

As shown, I wish to access the `CamelLoopIndex` and use it as an index in an array. The expression is not evaluated, hence the route is not created. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Documentation on this is pretty scanty, and I've not been successful getting a solution after hours of searching.

**UPDATE**: I've posted the same question to the Camel Users Mailing List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm late to the party but maybe somebody will get help from this answer. In the example given above this works for me for accessing the loop index in the Java DSL.

```
property(Exchange.LOOP_INDEX)
```

So for the example in the first post from okello above I guess this will work

```
Integer.valueOf(property(Exchange.LOOP_INDEX).toString())
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use ${property.CamelLoopIndex}

Comment: I've used this, but the expression somehow can't be resolved.

Comment: suppose you can use ${property.CamelLoopIndex} in "simple" expressions. If you don't use simple try property("CamelLoopIndex")

Comment: I just used an additional processor, in which I could extract the loop index by calling exchange.getProperty("CamelLoopIndex"), and use the index to get the actual value I wanted, set it in the header and access it in the subsequent route components. See the answer below (I posted my solution here).

Comment: i see. i just wanted to suggest easy way.

Comment: You are right. The reason it never worked for me is because I never explicitly defined the 'property' bean in my spring context. With the 'property' bean defined, it works fine. This feedback is late, but I hope someone might stumble on it and your way is definitely simpler. And so is @crea1's answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a [processor](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/processor.html) or directly access the property

```
${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}

...
    .loop(4)
       .log("${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}")
       .process(exchange -> {
          Integer index = (Integer) exchange.getProperty(Exchange.LOOP_INDEX);
       })
     .end()
...
```

[image]
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/loop-eip.html
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/processor.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Having experimented around with a number of options, the following works for me:

```
from("file:" + autoLoadBaseDir + "?preMove=inprogress&move=.classified")
                .routeId("Test-Route")
                .loop(fileTypes.length)
                .processRef("keFileTypeNameService")
                    .choice()
                        .when(header("CamelFileName").contains(header("MyFileType")))
                            .to("file:" + classesBaseDir + "/?autoCreate=true&fileName=${header[MyFileType]}/${header[CamelFileName]}");
```

The `keFileTypeNameService` retrieves the `CamelLoopIndex` property from the exchange. It then uses this to get the file type at that index. It then just simply set this file type name in the header. The `keFileTypeNameService` bean is shown below:

```
@Service( value = "keFileTypeNameService" )
public class FileTypeNameService implements Processor {

    private @Value("${ke.file.types}") String[] fileTypes;

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Integer count = exchange.getProperty("CamelLoopIndex", Integer.class);
        String fileType = fileTypes[count];
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("MyFileType", fileType);
    }




}
```

I hope this assists someone else.